# How deploy several VCN on different compartments inside Oracle Cloud?

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, terraform-modules

i have a big problem and i would like to know if there is someone here that can help me.

I create a small github project to show you the steps done, but at the end without positive results.

I need to create dynamic VCN on different compartments, using a json input file. The steps done was:

1. On the **xxxxxxxx_v1.tfvars.json** you can see the next. If I send the OCID of the compartment where i would like to set the new VCN's --> it works. But wht happens if instead using OCID i just know the name of the comparment instead OCID of the compartments?
2. For that reason I create **xxxxxxxx_v2.tfvars.json** where I'm sending the name of the compartments where i would like to deploy VCN. And also on the modeule folder there is a new version folder for network module. Where i use "data" to get compartment ID for each Compartment that comes on the json file, filtering per each compartment name.

But i have some error:

[image]

So about my question: how can I deploy VCN's on different compartment filtering by compartment_name dynamically.

So I upload my code on this public repo : https://github.com/juliovg/multiples_vcns.git

If some can help me with this and also how can i OUTPUT the list of compartments  ID's.

Comment: WHat is your current TF code? Also please do not post errors as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: the code is on the github project i paste on my question, because the project is a little big

Comment: And the error in code block? If you use images, no one can copy and paste any text from them.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think the line

```
compartment_id = data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment_id.0.id
```

should be:

```
compartment_id = data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment_id[0].id
```

And maybe, you should work with a lookup...

```
compartment_id = lookup(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment_id[0], "id")
```